# Pesky permission issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I wrote a very simple function in Google App Script:

```
function addProduct(number) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([number, number+1])
}
```

and tried to run it in Google Spreadsheets by entering `=addProduct()` in a cell. However, the Google Spreadsheets gave me an error that I don't have the *permission* to call the function appendRow().

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Every custom function must return a value to display.
- A custom function cannot affect cells other than those it returns a value to. In other words, a custom function cannot edit arbitrary cells, only the cells it is called from and their adjacent cells. To edit arbitrary cells, use a custom menu to run a function instead. Taken from: [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)